PostgreSQL Permission Denied After Docker Migration Between VPS Using rclone
[Help] PostgreSQL Permission Denied After Docker Migration Between VPS Using rclone
Problem
I'm getting permission denied errors while trying to set modification times on PostgreSQL files after migrating a Docker setup between VPS instances. Even with full permissions (777) and sudo, the errors persist.
Current Approach

Trying to migrate the entire Docker directory structure (not using pg_dump)
Stopped PostgreSQL containers on both VPS 1 and VPS 2 before migration
Note: I'm aware pg_dump works fine, but specifically need to migrate the entire folder structure

Environment

Docker container app running PostgreSQL
Migration from VPS 1 to VPS 2
Path: /opt/docker/my-docker-app/database/

Rclone Commands

My function:

 sync_operation() {
    local source="$1"
    local destination="$2"
    sudo rclone sync "$source" "$destination" \
        --sftp-host "$SSH_HOST" \
        --sftp-port "$SSH_PORT" \
        --sftp-user "$SSH_USER" \ # not root
        --sftp-key-file "$SSH_KEY" \
        --create-empty-src-dirs \
        --progress
    }


Example of usage:

SOURCE_DIR="/opt/docker/my-docker-app/database" # in VPS 1
DEST_DIR="/opt/docker/my-docker-app/database"  # in VPS 2
sync_operation "$SOURCE_DIR" ":sftp:$DEST_DIR"

Error Messages
ERROR : /my-docker-app/database/data/base/16384/13404: Failed to set modification time: SetModTime failed: permission denied
ERROR : /my-docker-app/database/data/base/16384/13406: Failed to set modification time: SetModTime failed: permission denied
ERROR : /my-docker-app/database/data/PG_VERSION: Failed to set modification time: SetModTime failed: permission denied

What I've Tried

Set full permissions: sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/docker/my-docker-app/database/
Used sudo for rclone sync operations
Checked file ownership (all failed files owned by systemd-coredump)

Questions

What's the proper way to handle file permissions during VPS migrations?
Are there specific considerations for PostgreSQL db file permissions in Docker environments?
Why I'm encountering this error?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Please update question with which version of Ubuntu you're using.
